# Alfred's Adult Piano Level 2 Augmented Chords page 130

Tags: chords, accidentals

On page 130 Alfred's Level 2 book is a sample of Augmented Chords, but for any chord which should have the middle note sharped, the middle sharp is dropped when converted to Augmented. I've looked on the internet, and everywhere else this does not happen.

Alfreds gives A Aug as this: A, C, E#.  The sharp for C is omitted.  He does the same thing with B Aug, D Aug, E Aug.  They all have sharps on the middle note of the chord and these sharps are dropped in the Augmented version.

Can anyone explain why he does this when I don't see it anywhere else?

Comment: Does this book show B augmented as B–D–Fx? D+ as D–F–A#? E+ as E–G–B#? If so, that's a definite error! All of these chordal thirds should have sharps on them.

Comment: One would hope that somewhere, earlier in the book, it would be stated that accidentals last through the whole bar.

Comment: on the grade when augmented chords are introduced I think the beginner should be on a level where he knows that rule of accidentals ...

Comment: Introducing the constituent notes of a newly defined type of chord in the middle of what is meant to be read as a bar of actual music is not a particularly great pedagogical decision

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The book shows the major chord followed by the corresponding augmented chord, both in the same measure. Because they're in the same measure, the accidental associated with the major chord carries over to the augmented chord as well. So, for example:

```
X: 1
T: Augmented chord
K: none
M: none
"A"[A^ce]4 "A aug"[Ac^e]4|
```

Here is an image (in the bass clef) from the 1984 edition of the book (page 76):

[image: D augmented chord example]

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I can see how this would be confusing; a parenthesized courtesy accidental probably would have been pedagogically wise.

Comment: @Richard Perhaps, although given the number of courtesy accidental questions we see here ... <g>

Comment: +1 - well spotted. Just when we thought we didn't need courtesy accidentals! In a beginner book, it would be more clear to use semibreves, one bar each. That would cut out any ambiguity. I often wonder what 'educators' are thinking...

Comment: For anyone, like me, who initially thought "huh?" at the second image above: it's the bass clef. My bad for too many years in brass bands ;)

Comment: In the first image, it's not clear that it _is_ a bar/measure; it could easily be isolated chords illustrating only the pitches, in which case it's not obvious that accidentals would carry through in the normal way.

Comment: @PhilMJones Good call. Thanks. I've added some text to clarify.

Comment: Haha this is a terrrrrible typographical decision!

Comment: In my own cheat sheets I put barlines or staff breaks between items like that. Surely they are isolated chords, not a progression. Make that visual, super obvious IMO.

Answer (score 0):

thankyou everyone.  This has cleared it up.  Of course, the accidentals carrying through in the same bar. I should be more awake.